# Printing from Different Trays on a Duplex Printer (Word 2003)

Tags: vba, printing, properties, ms-word, duplex

I am making a macro which prints page 1 From one tray which has headed paper and all other pages from another tray.

This works fine apart from the printer duplex's it, so it comes out back to front and upside down.

Is there a way to make it not come upside and possible rotate everything on the page by 180 degrees ?

Or disable duplexing using `acPRDPSimplex`

Here is the code:

```
Sub PrintHeaded()
findprinter
Dim VNumberofPages As Integer
ActiveDocument.Repaginate
VNumberofPages = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages)
If VNumberofPages = 1 Then
    vprintrange = "1"
    ActiveDocument.PageSetup.FirstPageTray = LetterHeadTray
Else: vprintrange = "1,2"
   ActiveDocument.PageSetup.FirstPageTray = LetterHeadTray
End If
        Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Item:= _
        wdPrintDocumentContent, Copies:=1, Pages:=vprintrange, PageType:= _
        wdPrintAllPages, ManualDuplexPrint:=False, Collate:=True, Background:= _
        True, PrintToFile:=False, PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, _
        PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0, OutputFileName:="", _
        Append:=False
If VNumberofPages > 2 Then
    vprintrange = "1 - " & VNumberofPages
    With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
        .FirstPageTray = LetterHeadTray
        .OtherPagesTray = PlainPaperTray
    End With
        Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Item:= _
        wdPrintDocumentContent, Copies:=1, Pages:=vprintrange, PageType:= _
        wdPrintAllPages, ManualDuplexPrint:=False, Collate:=True, Background:= _
        True, PrintToFile:=False, PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, _
        PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0, OutputFileName:="", _
        Append:=False
End If
```

End Sub